# javafx combobox event listner exception

Tags: java, exception, combobox, javafx-2, javafx

I want to get the selected value of the combobox and do some proccessing on it. I do get the value in println but some times after a consecutive change of selection in the combobox, I am usually getting exceptions.

Due to those exceptions the selected item in combobox gets to (no selected value) . I mean an error.

am I making a mistake in my code or what is the

```
superTypeComboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1) {
        System.out.println(superTypeComboBox.getValue().toString());
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

    });
```

i do get println of first selection . i.e Cash 02 (below) but when i change the selection second time. i get the following exception and the selection isnt changed.

the third time i change the selection. it works and i get the println. 
the forth time is same as second time. and so on.

```
Cash    02
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at accountsMain.AccountsMainController$1.changed(AccountsMainController.java:238)
    at accountsMain.AccountsMainController$1.changed(AccountsMainController.java:224)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:123)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:148)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:416)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$300(ComboBox.java:166)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$6.changed(ComboBox.java:401)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:101)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:214)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:142)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$7.invalidated(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:531)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:359)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:294)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:269)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.simpleSelect(ListCellBehavior.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.doSelect(ListCellBehavior.java:167)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.mousePressed(ListCellBehavior.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.valueInvalidated(ComboBoxBase.java:117)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase$1.invalidated(ComboBoxBase.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:148)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:416)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$300(ComboBox.java:166)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$6.changed(ComboBox.java:401)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:101)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel$1.invalidated(ComboBox.java:448)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:208)
    at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:142)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$7.invalidated(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:531)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:359)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:294)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:269)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.simpleSelect(ListCellBehavior.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.doSelect(ListCellBehavior.java:167)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListCellBehavior.mousePressed(ListCellBehavior.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at accountsMain.AccountsMainController$1.changed(AccountsMainController.java:228)
    at accountsMain.AccountsMainController$1.changed(AccountsMainController.java:224)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:123)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:148)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.updateValue(ComboBox.java:416)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.access$300(ComboBox.java:166)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$6.changed(ComboBox.java:401)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:101)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel$1.invalidated(ComboBox.java:448)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:195)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:130)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel.updateItemsObserver(ComboBox.java:519)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel.access$000(ComboBox.java:435)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$4.invalidated(ComboBox.java:267)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.setItems(ComboBox.java:275)
    at accountsMain.AccountsMainController.handleAddCOA(AccountsMainController.java:222)
    ... 98 more
```

Comment: You did not finish your question. Please post error messages also.

Comment: coz u a fir'n ex there. "Not supported yet."

Comment: @UlukBiy yes, but it should let me select or change selection and still println. I have added the exception message above

Comment: @masood what you have at AccountsMainController.java:228?

Comment: @UlukBiy http://pastie.org/5088669

Comment: why do you throw `UnsupportedOperationException` at the end of your handler?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev should I not? its auto coded by netbeans.

Comment: surely no! It's a placeholder until you add real code!

Comment: @SergeyGrinev ok. could you show me by code how should the code look like. anyother changes? or betterment?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev well, i have removed the throws exception but I still get the mentioned error

Comment: @masood post the full runnable and simplified code sample demonstrating the error. Otherwise try yourself to debug your code line by line.

Comment: @UlukBiy I have already edited my post and added the code + error

Answer (score 0):

The very last exception is a NullPointerException.  Do a null check on superTypeComboBox.getValue() before you call toString on it.

Or... you don't need to do a null check, just remove the toString call, if the object is null then println will print "null" to the console.

Comment: look near 240 - 260 .http://pastie.org/5088669 I need .toString() to process the selected item of combobox. can you elaborate by code (what you mean)?

Comment: You have a NullPointerException in your logs so the return value of superTypeComboBox.getValue() might be null.  Do a null check before calling toString() on it.

Comment: you mean if(superTypeComboBox.getValue().toString() != null){do some process} ?  i should inform you again that the error happens on the 2nd time (when I 'reslectect' a new item in list)

Comment: Try if(superTypeComboBox.getValue() != null) {} this should be very easy to confirm by debugging.

Comment: but that will not allow me if theres already a selection made in the combobox and the user wants to reselect a new item. thats whats happening already.

Comment: comprende? sory i didnt got that

Answer (score 0):

You Get combobox selected value use method getselectionmodel for combobox i will explain this exmaple.

**Example:-**

```
mycombobox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new  
  ChangeListener<String>() 
{
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,String  
    oldValue,String newValue) 
    {
        system.Out.Println("Value is::"+newValue);
    }   
});
```